# Unable to access variable outside of arrow function in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arrow-functions

I have declare array out side of arrow function then pushing values in it inside arrow function but that array is only available inside of arrow function outside of it array is empty.

```
 var listings = [];
  

  
  dbRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((listing) => {
    
      listings.push(listing.val());
    });
  
  
  });

  console.log('listing',listings);
```

console log display array value only inside of arrow function, what could be the reason

Comment: The callback is asynchronous, you're logging the value before it has executed.

Comment: What should be the method then?

Comment: Put it inside the callback function.